# How do you use VLOOKUP with a loop in Excel VBA to write data into multiple sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write information onto multiple sheets in excel using loops and VLookup, that all get their information from the same Input sheet. It works perfectly for one sheet, but I keep getting an error that it's "Unable to get the VLookup property of the Worksheet Function class" for the other sheets. The error is in variable Wave(i).

```
Function Waves(BN() As Integer, Table As Range, Wave() As String, _
               wsName As String, numRows As Integer)
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To numRows
    BN(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).Range("A" & i + 2) 'change 5k to a string variable
    Set Table = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cleaned Input").Range("Table2")
    Wave(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(BN(i), Table, 13)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).Range("F" & i + 2) = Wave(i)
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

If you drop the `WorksheetFunction` you can test the Vlookup return value using `IsError()`.  If you include WorksheetFunction, you get a runtime error in the event Vlookup doesn't find a match.

```
Function Waves(BN() As Integer, Table As Range, Wave() As String, _
                   wsName As String, numRows As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer, v, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    Set Table = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cleaned Input").Range("Table2")

    For i = 0 To numRows
        BN(i) = ws.Range("A" & i + 2) 'change 5k to a string variable
        v = Application.VLookup(BN(i), Table, 13, False)
        If IsError(v) Then v = "No Match"       
        Wave(i) = v
        ws.Range("F" & i + 2) = v
    Next

End Function
```

BTW this really should be a Sub since it doesn't directly return a value.

Comment: What's the benefit of this parameter `Wave() As String`?! The ranges are filled with the value of the variable v and I think no need for it in this case.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is using that and `BN()` as in/out parameters (returned by reference to the calling procedure)